# SQL Missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select the data where the gender is female or x. It can not be male the code I am using returns Missing Expression :

```
    SELECT pet_id, name, gender, type, breed
    FROM Pet
    WHERE Name Like '%s' or Name like 'S%'
    And WHERE Gender ='F' or Gender ='X';
```

Is my formatting okay?

Comment: That 2nd where is not valid - `Where (Name Like '%s' or Name like 'S%') And Gender IN ('F', 'X');`

Comment: yeah you only use one "where" in a query unless you are doing a subquery/union/etc, you chain additional clauses with AND or OR

Comment: do syntax errors qualify for stack overflow ques?

Answer (score 1):

In your query you have used the `where` keyword twice which is not valid.
The sql syntax prohibits you from doing so, you can have one `from` and `where` per `select` keyword.
to select multiple fields, you separate by commas.
to select from multiple tables, you separate by commas.
to use multiple conditions in your where clause you use `and` & `or` (this rule applies to most programming languages, you cannot have for example `if(x1==1 and if (x2==2))` instead you use `if(x1==1 && x2==2)` )
also try using the `in` operator for your condition on gender, as such

```
Gender in('F','X')
```

the in operator allows you to check if the value of a given column exists in an array/list/series of possible values.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated "where" in your query. Rewrite in following way should work:

```
SELECT pet_id, name, gender, type, breed
FROM Pet
WHERE (Name Like '%s' or Name like 'S%') AND (Gender ='F' or Gender ='X');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT pet_id,name,gender,type,breed FROM Pet
Where (Name Like '%s' or Name like 'S%')
And (Gender ='F' or Gender ='X');
```

We can't use 'Where' multiple times in single query and as i see in your case you should apply round brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Remove second WHERE and don't forget brackets:

```
SELECT pet_id, name, gender, type, breed
    FROM Pet
    WHERE (Name Like '%s' or Name like 'S%')
       And Gender in ('F','X')
```